# Calling $.getJSON within a function returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting data from a device and placing the result in a web page. When I run this code from within a window.setInterval function I'm able to see the values without any issue

```
requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/" + getYFunc + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
$.getJSON(requestURL, function(json) {
  document.getElementById("curYPos").innerHTML = json.result + "&deg;";
  document.getElementById("curYPos").style.fontSize = "18px";
});
```

When I run the same code within a function and try to return the value I still  get value on the page but when I try to read the value from the function, I get an "Undefined":

```
function getAccelData(aAxis) //This pulls the Accel data down by Axis for use 
{
    requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/" + getXFunc + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
    $.getJSON(requestURL, function(json) {
      document.getElementById("curXPos").innerHTML = json.result + "&deg;";
      document.getElementById("curXPos").style.fontSize = "18px";
      return json.result;
    });
}
```

In this example I'm not even passing the parameter in from the function, I just copied the code that I knew worked and then tried to pass the json.result out. I'm sure it's something simple but I have not been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use console.log inside your function to debug. For instance, console.log(json.result); inside function.

Comment: Your function ends before the async call is completed.  That's why you get undefined.

Comment: Thanks Quentin and Nino. I'll look at the response and also go through the other questions. I'm assuming that I just need to wait until the response comes back via a loop?